# Combine Touching Lines into Combined Line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry, line

I have a set of lines. Every line is consists of set of x, y coordinates. I need to combine lines which intersect at the edge of line.

Any opencv or shapely implementations are welcome.

Here is example image of all lines (draw in random colors for distinction)

[image]

Comment: It is worth to show a picture. I'd like to see "the edge of line" and so on.

Comment: Search each end point for close other endpoints, then for close ones check the slopes of each line to see if similar enough. Or use Hough line transform.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42. I did as you said. It worked

Comment: `@Elbek` Post your solution to help others.